# Angular broadcast

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i want to send parameters using Angualr broadcast

From one of my controller i do

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('handlemodeldelete', Idx); // I broadcast value 6
```

and in another controller i have listener

```
 $scope.$on('handlemodeldelete', function(Idx)
 {

  });
```

But Idx value reaches like this after i see from debug window.

```
currentScope: ChildScope
defaultPrevented: false
name: "handlemodeldelete"
preventDefault: ()
targetScope: Scope
__proto__: Object
```

Any clue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to your listener function is an event object, then any arguments used in the call to $broadcast come next.  Define your handler as follows:

```
$scope.$on('handlemodeldelete', function(event, Idx)
        {

        });
```

See the AngularJS docs for more info:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

Comment: thanks. This solved the problem. But i have the same code else and there it works. I am wondering why ?

Comment: Not sure.  Is it the same version of AngularJS?  It is possible that the interface changed?  Post the other code so I can take a look.

Comment: Its same version of angularJS since it is same project and exactly same code. Just the handler name different.Strange . But thanks a lot.:)

Answer (score 1):

First param is the event. You need to add another parameter:

```
$scope.$on('handlemodeldelete', function(e, Idx){
    console.log("Event", e);
    console.log("IDX", Idx);
});
```

An example for passing multiple params would be:

```
$scope.$broadcast('eventName', { message: msg,  message2: msg2  });


$scope.$on('eventName', function (event, args) {
     console.log(args.message);
     console.log(args.message2);
});
```

More info at Angular Docs: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast